# Определение нахождения на определенной странице

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста с вопросом. Я создал новость. Затем разместил в колонке сайта. Эта новость хранится в бд. То есть при нажатии на эту новость происходит переход на страницу, в котором написано более подробная информация. И надо чтоб при посещении этой страницы исчезала новость из колонки. Будьте добры, помоги, пожалуйста, как это реализовать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В коде показа баннера сделайте проверку переменной, например, которая будет сначала false, и баннер показать, а при выписке полной новости выставляйте ее true, и баннер скрывать по этому значению. Или наоборот, тут уж как удобнее.

Либо если баннер показывает отрывки новостей, то делаете переменную с ИД этой новости, а при выписке в баннер проверяете переменную, и с данным ид не выписываете.

Answer (score 1):

Например у вас страница новости - **http://site/news?id=2**

В запросе который формирует данные колонки просто добавляем
`WHERE id != "$_GET['id']"` таким образом текущая новость никак не попадет в вашу колонку...